# How can I allow bash -c for sudoers (followed by multiple commands)?

Tags: bash, sudo, sudoers

I have this in /etc/sudoers:

```
%wheel myhostname =NOPASSWD: /bin/bash -c "echo foo && echo bar", \
                             /bin/bash -c echo foo
```

Executing `sudo /bin/bash -c echo foo` works without being prompted for a password.

However, `sudo /bin/bash -c "echo foo && echo bar"` still asks for a password.

I've tried *many* variations to this, but nothing is being accepted.

**Where's the error? / How can I allow -c followed by multiple commands?**

Comment: One obvious work-around: call it a script in /usr/local/bin and refer to that script in /etc/sudoers :)

Comment: @user3159253 that's my current approach - which I want to get away from :)

Comment: Ehhm, the most obvious solutions are often the best :) The sudoers manpage mentiones that special symbols which to be passed to shell should be backslash-protected, but I don't see any of them in your command.

Comment: Additional files would complicate my setup, as there is more than one script affected - and multiple machines. I also had tested with `sudo /bin/bash -c \"echo foo && echo bar\"` - without success.

Comment: Did you try `\&\&` ?

Comment: @BeniBela Yes :) Been at it for (felt) hours.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. `%wheel myhostname =NOPASSWD: /bin/bash -c "echo foo && echo bar"` works well with Ubuntu 11.04. `sudo /bin/bash -c echo foo` without quotation marks won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least with my `sudo` (OS X 10.9, sudo 1.7.10p7), quote marks in the `/etc/sudoers` are matched literally. That is, specifying

```
/bin/bash -c "echo foo && echo bar"
```

means that the users literally have to run

```
sudo /bin/bash -c '"echo foo && echo bar"'
```

i.e. the quote marks have to be passed to the program.

Therefore, all you have to do is just drop the quote marks in /etc/sudoers:

```
%wheel myhostname =NOPASSWD: /bin/bash -c echo foo && echo bar
```

While this looks kind of weird, it completely works on my machine: users can execute `/bin/bash -c "echo foo && echo bar"` without a password. This works because, according to `man sudoers`, the only characters that must be escaped are `',', ':', '=' and '\'`.

Note that this implies that `sudo` is basically concatenating all the command-line args together with only spaces to determine a match: users can also execute `/bin/bash -c "echo foo" "&&" "echo bar"`. Therefore, you must take care that none of the arguments could individually be a security risk (e.g. that `foo`, `&&` and `bar` aren't things that could be used to exploit your computer).

Comment: Thanks. I gave the bounty to @Austin for for his explanation and accepted your answer, as it's the "quicker read" for others looking for a solution.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in how your shell interprets arguments.  If I am in bash (most other shells work the same way), and I type the command

```
sudo /bin/bash -c "echo foo && echo bar"
```

`sudo` is invoked with everything after it as arguments.  However, the shell processes each argument before passing it in to `sudo`.  One of the things it does is remove quotes around quoted arguments.  Therefore, the arguments that `sudo` gets as its `argv` value are an array that looks like this (one argument per line):

```
/bin/bash
-c
echo foo && echo bar
```

`sudo` combines these with spaces and compares that to the commands in the sudoers file (it is actually a bit more complicated than this since it does wildcard replacement, etc.).  Thus, the command it actually sees you executing, for the purposes of checking permissions is

```
/bin/bash -c echo foo && echo bar
```

When I put that command in my sudoers file, I am not prompted for a password when I enter

```
sudo /bin/bash -c "echo foo && echo bar"
```

However I am also not prompted for a password when I enter any of these commands or other like them.

```
sudo /bin/bash "-c echo foo && echo bar"
sudo /bin/bash "-c echo" foo "&& echo" bar
sudo /bin/bash -c echo "foo && echo" bar
```

In general, as far as I know, there is no way for `sudo` (or any program) to know *exactly* what command got entered, only what it gets converted to by the shell for execution purposes.